# Delayed Job just not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, delayed-job

I am building an application where at some point I need to sync a bunch of data from fb with my database, so I am (attemtping) to use Delayed Job to push this into the background.  Here is what part of my Delayed Job class looks like.

```
class FbSyncJob < Struct.new(:user_id)
  require 'RsvpHelper'

  def perform
    user = User.find(user_id)
    FbSyncJob.sync_user(user)
  end

  def FbSyncJob.sync_user(user)
    friends = HTTParty.get(
      "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=#{user.fb['token']}"
    )
    friends_list = friends["data"].map { |friend| friend["id"] }
    user.fb["friends"] = friends_list
    user.fb["sync"]["friends"] = Time.now
    user.save!
    FbSyncJob.friend_crawl(user)
  end
end
```

With the `RsvpHelper` class living in `lib/RsvpHelper.rb`.  So at some point in my application I call `Delayed::Job.enqueue(FbSyncJob.new(user.id))` with a known valid user.  The worker I set up even tells me that the job has been completed successfully:

`1 jobs processed at 37.1777 j/s, 0 failed`

However when I check the user in the database he has not had his friends list updated.  Am I doing something wrong or what?  Thanks so much for the help this has been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Delayed::Job.enqueue` will put a record in the delayed job table, but you need to run a seperate process to execute the job code (perform method)

typically in development this would be `bundle exec rake jobs:work` (NOTE: you must restart this rake task anytime you make code changes, it will not auto load changes)

- see https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs

I usually put the following into my delayed configuration while in development - this never puts a record in the delayed job table and runs all background code synchronously (in development) and by default rails will reload changes to your code

`Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !(Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?)`

- https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#gory-details (see config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb example section)

Comment: This would be easier to read:  `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = Rails.env.production?`

Comment: @Lane - what about staging environment?